# pulling alt and title from ACF image array

Tags: php, title, advanced-custom-fields, alt

Trying to pull alt and title tag for a image via ACF using the image array. This is what I have been doing and it seems to work most of the time but I can't get it to work this time.

Here is my code.

See anything off?

```
<div class="slide-img">
  <?php
  $image = get_field('slide_image_1');
  ?>
<img class="rsImg" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>">
</div>
```

slide_image_1 is my ACF name

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<pre> 
<?php print_r($image); ?> 
</pre>
```

to output an image object and see if the image was actually supplied by acf and which image object/array fields are available. If alt and other image fields are there, then it should be working

Comment: BTW you are echoing an $image in src. If you have an image array than you should be echoing $image['url'] or url or whatever is supplied.

Answer (score 2):

When you echo the image field directly, `<?php echo $image; ?>` you are simply outputting the whole array, given that you set the image field to output `Image Object`, when you made the field.

You need to add the object you need from the array, as you did with the `alt` and `title`, so your final image tag will be:

`<img class="rsImg" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>">`

Always try `var_dump` or `print_r` as the other answer mentioned, when you see something not working, this way you'll be able to see what's returned and grab the correct data you need.